# PHP - как выделить именах файлов общие корни-маски?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть много файлов с именами:

```
file_des_2020051000_.txt
ptrfile_2020012120_.txt
msk_fin_2020451000_.txt
file_des_20200701_.txt
ptrfile_232342.txt
```

Как выделить-сгруппировать из всех имен файлов общие маски? Определить их и сгруппировать.
Итог должен быть:

```
file_des_20200.*
ptrfile_2.*
file_des_20200701_.txt
msk_fin_2020451000_.txt
```

Подтолкните на мысль пожалуйста.

Comment: мне вот пока что не ясно, каков критерий общей маски. где надо остановится, чтобы общее не свелось к `f*, p*, m*`. Не понятно, почему у вас `file_des` не сложились в одну строку. и что будет если будут файлы `file_des_20201...` `file_des20202` и `file_des20211` это будет общая `file_des202*` или две `file_des2020*` & `file_des20211`

Comment: Проблема и в том, что общей маски нет. Нужно её выделить. Нет паттернов для масок.

Comment: я вам в комментарии пример привел с тремя файлами и двумя вариантами ответа. сформулируйте критерий этой "общей" маски, почему она должна быть именно "такая" а не более общая.

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбивать имена файлов на части, например по символу "_". Далее считать число вхождений, позицию вхождений и на основе частотности уже формировать символьную маску.

Потом брать одну символьную маску, отбирать файлы относящиеся к ней и считать цифровую часть маски посимвольно. Например, 2, потом 20, потом 2020 и уже на основании некоего порога вхождения в именах файлов уже формировать числовую маску.
Числовую маску посимвольно проверять только на начало числовой части, не брать любое вхождение. Вхождение в середине числа не нужно.
Далее просто склеивать символьную и числовую в итоговую маску.

Порог количества вхождений определите экспериментально, исходя из требуемого конечного результата группировки.